# How to fix corrupted sales_flat_order_item data

Tags: magento-1.9

Some of our installed modules have messed up our `sales_flat_order_item` data, and now I'm trying to fix the data. Some items only have configurable records and no simple records, I need to add the simple record so that our reports can work again, I'm thinking of taking the configurable record's data and create a record for the simple but I don't know how to get the correct data for `product_options` column. Does anyone have any thoughts on what function to use so that I can serialize the correct data for `product_options` column?

Comment: You can use the Magento db repair tool for this may that will help you